# How to deploy truffle project on web server?

Tags: truffle, dapp-development, truffle-deployment, build-from-source

I've developed a DApp using truffle suite and now I want to deploy this dapp online so that everyone will be able to access it over the internet.

I've used Rinkeby-Testnet for smart contract deployment.  Whenever I use `npm run dev` command, it deploy the frontend of dapp on locally using lite-server but, now I want to publish it globally and have no idea about it.

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the tutorial on this site: https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is that you can purchase or try free tier ec2 instance of AWS for deploy and install truffle over there then you can access it globally.
Hope this will help you.